# Unable to invoke click method on selected element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I need to click on a particular button in a Google MyBusiness page. The problem is that no click is happening.

Screenshot shows the button which is supposed to be clicked focused. The html of the element is:

```
<div role="button" class="U26fgb zg hx mZ r2" jscontroller="VXdfxd" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;"
    jsshadow="" jsname="BddwAf" aria-label="Remove" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0">
    <div class="Ci he" jsname="ksKsZd"></div>
    <content class="gx"><span style="top: -12px"><svg xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                <path d="M19 6.41L17.59 5 12 10.59 6.41 5 5 6.41 10.59 12 5 17.59 6.41 19 12 13.41 17.59 19 19 17.59 13.41 12z"></path>
                <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"></path>
            </svg></span></content>
</div>
```

I have tried to do a wide search for similiar elements with the following selector:

```
hoursdiv = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@role = "button"]')
    for el in hoursdiv:
        print(el)
        el.click
```

Output:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-5")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-6")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-7")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-8")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-9")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-10")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-11")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-12")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-13")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-14")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-15")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-16")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-17")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-18")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-19")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-20")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-21")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-22")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-23")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-24")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-25")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-26")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-27")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-28")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="837341007f4b88350c3449e07e291d82", element="0.27450440234933726-29")>
```

But the element is not getting clicked.
The html of the section where these elements are displayed is uploaded [here](https://pastebin.com/32MjjjD2).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to wait until modal window with `X` buttons appeared and use more specific locator to select buttons:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

buttons = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[arial-label="Remove"] svg')))
for button in buttons:
    button.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

The element which you are trying to click is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element, so you have to induce *WebDriverwait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solution:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  hoursdiv = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[role='button'][aria-label='Remove']")))
  for el in hoursdiv:
      print(el)
      el.click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  hoursdiv = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@role='button' and @aria-label='Remove']")))
  for el in hoursdiv:
      print(el)
      el.click()
  ```
- Note: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I assume wait is not your problem, it need two click, `div` and `<content class="gx">`